# PHP cURL body does not work with multiple arrays

Tags: php, sql-server, rest, curl

I need to send a data via `cURL` in `PHP`. 
There is my `POST` request and it works with this example (I can post 1 record).

```
 $postData = array(
           "username" => "email@domain.com",
            "name" => "Name",
            "surname" => "Surname",
            'role' => 'user',
            "disabled" => "false"


      );

        $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->getCurlUrl());
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
 curl_setopt_array($ch, 
               array(
                   CURLOPT_POST => false,
                   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    'authorization: apikey '.$apikey,
                    'Content-Type: application/rest+json',
                    'pincode: '.$pincode
                                              )
                  // ,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
   ));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , json_encode($postData));
 $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // this results 0 every time
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 if ($response === false) $response = curl_error($ch);
 return stripslashes($response);
 curl_close($ch);
```

But I would like to add records from database into `$postData` `array` but then it's stops.

This is my database array example:

```
$postData = array();

  foreach ($records = $this->getRecords as $value) {

        $row['username'] = $value['email'];
        $row['name'] = $value['name'];
        $row['surname'] = $value['surname'];
        $row['role'] = 'User';
        $row['disabled'] = $value['status'];

        array_push($postData, $row); 



      }
```

`json` array looks `ok` but I can't find an error. Or i can't post multiple data and i need to add  everything in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

I find a few flaws in the code. You said that you are posting the code but you have set

```
CURLOPT_POST => false
```

Also, you have repeated

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE and CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
```

Also, your API might be designed to accept one record but you are trying to send multiple records. If it is designed to accept 1 record at a time you should make the curl call a function and call it in place of array_push. eg:. curlfunction($row);

```
 function curlfunction($postData){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->getCurlUrl());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST , 1);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'authorization: apikey '.$apikey,
                'Content-Type: application/rest+json',
                'pincode: '.$pincode
             )

      );
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , json_encode($postData));
      $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
      $response = curl_exec($ch);
      if ($response === false) $response = curl_error($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return stripslashes($response);
  }
```

and

```
  foreach ($records = $this->getRecords as $value) {

    $row['username'] = $value['email'];
    $row['name'] = $value['name'];
    $row['surname'] = $value['surname'];
    $row['role'] = 'User';
    $row['disabled'] = $value['status'];

    curlfunction($row); 



  }
```